# How to cancel update in sqldatasource_updating event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource.

I can't find a way to cancel the update the update without closing the row from the edit event. because e.cancel is not available in updating event.

I need to do it in UPDATED not in UPDATING because in updating I can't get some events.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `e.KeepInEditMode = true;` to keep the updated record in edit mode. but you can't cancel updating in `updated`, because record has already been updated till that. you will to have find another way to do it, with custom coding.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated">
</asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
 {
            e.KeepInEditMode = true;
 }
```

in case of sqldatasource

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
 {
            e.Command.Cancel();
 }
```

Comment: I can't access keepinEdit mode , it doesn't exists

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.KeepInEditMode = true;
        }

Comment: yes but , I need to keep it in edit only when I'm getting an error in sqldatasource_UPDATED

Comment: protected void SqlDataSource1_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Command.Cancel();
        }